# How to persist data in a PHP application

Tags: php

Why might a static variable I've initialized in a class become unset? Here is class( is 'static' ):

```
class Events {
    // static events collection
    private static $events = null;

    // private(unused) constructor
    private function __construct() {}

    // initializes the class
    public static function initialize($events){
        self::$events = $events;        
    }

    // returns the event collection
    public static function get(){
        return self::$events;
    }
}
```

I set $events like this:

```
functions.php:
include_once "events.php";

// a function to initialize the application
function init(){
    // retrieve events from database
    $events = get_events_from_server();

    // initialize the events class
    Events::initialize($events);
}
```

init() is called from index.php.
The variable seems to be unset after index.php has completely loaded. I post from javascript to a server page: get_events.php to request the list of json encoded events. At get_events.php the static events variable is null. Here is get_events.php:

```
<?php 
    include_once "../ccc-psl-config.php";
    include_once WEBROOT ."/includes/functions.php";
    include_once WEBROOT ."/includes/db_connect.php";
    include_once WEBROOT ."/types/events.php";

    ob_start();

    try{
        // open database connection
        $pdo = DatabaseConnection::open();    
        $events = Events::get();
        //$events = get_events($pdo);

        if($events){
            echo $events;
        }
        else {
            echo false;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        print_r("Failed to get events from database: ".$e.getMessage());
        echo false;
    }

    // close database connection
    DatabaseConnection::close();

    ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: And at what point is it vanishing?

Comment: Seems to vanish after the rest of index.php has completely loaded

Comment: You mean it vanishes when the script terminates? That would be logical: static !== persistent between requests

Comment: @MarkBaker ok. i'm new to php. how can i persist data without the use of superglobals? Database only?

Comment: Superglobals won't persist either.... you need to understand the PHP execution model, request starts, request executes, request terminates.... unless data is persisted between requests, it is flushed from memory after every request.... you can persist data to filesystem, database, session or dedicated caches such as redis, memcache, APCu or similar

Comment: @MarkBaker What would make the implementation of static variables useful?

Comment: Once defined, the static variable exists as long as the request is executing (unless modified) without needing to instantiate any object, and is directly accessible from any scope

Comment: @MarkBaker You should add your comment as an answer since the question is clearly the missunderstand of the OP about the PHP execution model (on your words).